# NO ME CARGAN LA IMAGEN EN LOS ESTILOS CSS EN DJANGO

Tags: python, css, django

No puedo visualizar la imagen en estilo CSS. Estoy creando un header para un menú y sigo estos pasos pero la imagen no se ve.

```
.header{
    background-image: url("{% static 'app/img/bg.jpg' %}");
}
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Ten siempre presente que mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR. 2. En el _settings.py_, ¿está `STATIC_URL`? ¿Está bien la ruta de tu imagen? ¿Repasaste la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/)? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.